# Why did my question asking for help debugging jQuery event handlers get downvoted and close-voted?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, specific-question, downvotes

So, I post a legitimate question about the Firefox Debugger on Stack Overflow:

[How do I debug jQuery events using Firefox debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726269/how-do-i-debug-jquery-events-using-firefox-debugger)

In come the negative votes and a couple votes to close the question. Why does this happen to me?

Answer (score 12):

Oy vey.

So, first off... Search! There are multiple previous questions regarding debugging jQuery events, including [this immensely popular discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool). Now, it's entirely possible that those won't help you, either because you're trying to do something a bit different or because they're out-of-date - but either way, you can save folks a lot of time wondering whether or not you've seen them by *referencing* those past topics in your own.

That out of the way, you did a pretty reasonable job of showing your work - kudos! However, you left out a pretty key piece of information:

> If I inspect the code, there are little "ev" tags on certain DOM elements. Supposedly you can click those and see the code.
>
> [image]
>
> Well, that was fruitless.

Uh... Your screenshot shows you looking right at the code within jQuery that handles the event - in other words, it's doing exactly what it purports to do. Again, if you'd read the previous discussions you'd know how to get from this to *your own code* - **or** you'd be looking at a great opportunity to explain why you couldn't.

There are probably a few other areas where you could improve that question (for instance, including the example code you're debugging *in the question itself!*) but those are the big ones IMHO.